# How do you combine artefacts from multiple builds in Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project where I need to perform multiple builds - across different agents. I have a Visual Studio project, an Xcode project and a NPM+Gulp project where I need to combine the artefacts into a single archive.

I have set up builds for each. And my first try was to set up a Release which downloaded the artefacts from each build and packaged it all up. But I didn't figure out how to get that package from the Release. (I had tried to use the Publish Artefact step, but got and error because apparently it can only be used for a Build)

So now I'm looking at creating a separate Build that does the packaging - and then puts the result in its Artefacts. But this made me wonder if there are better ways to deal with this in Team Services?

What I also want to achieve here is to trigger builds of my VS, Xcode and NPM Builds when I push to my git repo, then have "something" kick of a packaging step when all those three builds are done. What's a good way to do that in Team Services?

Comment: If they all belong together, why don't they all happen in a single build?

Comment: Can you have single build use different agents? Because I need a Windows agent for the Visual Studio build and a Mac agent for the Xcode build.

Comment: Sure. Look at multi-phase builds.

Comment: Aaah! I had not seen that! Well that should solve my case. If you post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you're describing sounds like you want everything to be a part of a single build, not separate builds.

Since you have some pieces that run on Windows and some that run on MacOS, you can use [multi-phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/phases?view=vsts&tabs=web) builds to run different "sections" of the build across different agents.